# MySql search query to ignore line breaks in data

Tags: mysql

**Example Data:**
"1\n
Example Road\n
Exampleton\n
AB1 2CD"
*(Each line break was created with '\n')*

**Search string:** "1 Example Road"

Need to be able to ignore the line breaks and return the result with something like:

SELECT `multilineAddressField` FROM table WHERE `multilineAddressField` LIKE '%$searchString%'

I assume it should be some form of Regex solution, but I'm not sure how to implement. Or, is there a neater solution?

Comment: `WHERE replace(multilineAddressField, '\n', '') LIKE '%$searchString%'`

Comment: @bansi - That worked beautifully. Thanks.  The form won't let me vote for your solution as it's a comment on mine (I think).  If you post it as an answer, I'll vote for it.  Thanks again.

Comment: nice to hear it worked for you. and don't worry about the vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regular expression

```
SELECT multilineAddressField FROM table WHERE 
multilineAddressField REGEXP  "1[:space:]Example Road"
```

if you think the sequence really would contain a newline followed by a space (as shown in your example)

```
SELECT multilineAddressField FROM table WHERE 
multilineAddressField REGEXP  "1[:space:]+Example Road"
```

Comment: I think that would work, but I don't know what the search string will be - it is supplied by the user..